# Is there a way to order by date only in timestamp colum using elquent of laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Let say I want a query with order by date, then order by another column `Testing Done`, like the following:

```
Item ID    Created At               Testing Done
-------------------------------------------------
5          2016-01-01 01:00:10      Not Done
1          2016-01-01 00:00:00      Done
2          2016-01-01 02:02:00      Done
4          2016-02-01 00:10:11      Not Done
3          2016-02-01 00:00:00      Done
6          2016-02-01 01:11:10      Done
```

i.e. The item should order first by date section of the timestamp "Created At", then order by if testing is done.

However, when I try to do ordering by this:

```
$testingItem = TestingItem::orderBy('create_at', 'asc')->orderBy('testing_done', 'asc')->paginate(10);
```

The result will look like this:

```
Item ID    Created At               Testing Done
-------------------------------------------------
1          2016-01-01 00:00:00      Done
5          2016-01-01 01:00:10      Not Done
2          2016-01-01 02:02:00      Done
3          2016-02-01 00:00:00      Done
4          2016-02-01 00:10:11      Not Done
6          2016-02-01 01:11:10      Done
```

The query take `created_at` as a whole timestamp. Is there a way I can build a query using eloquent of laravel to get the correct result?

Comment: How do you want it to be sorted?

Comment: The first table is what I want it to be like. I have edited some wordings to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this

```
$testingItem = TestingItem::orderByRaw('DATE(created_at)')->orderBy('testing_done', 'asc')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

As i don't have any experience in laravel. But according to mysql you can try like below

```
SELECT *, DATE(create_at) as date
FROM tablename

ORDER BY date ASC, testing_done ASC
```